# In PostgreSQL, how do I read in tab-delimited data that contains a space?

Tags: postgresql, backup, pgadmin

Postgres thinks my last column of data, containing two words separated by a space, is two columns of data.

My query:

```
COPY public.assets (id, name, model, category, brand)
FROM '/home/123_COPY.sql'
DELIMITER E'\t'
CSV HEADER;
```

The error in PgAdmin:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY assets, line 2: "a11bc222-d3ee-4f55-gg6h-777i88j9k00 DB-DA-AB22-10   Inspiron    Tech    Desktop Dell"
SQL state: 22P04
```

Comment: Check the file. Hexdump it. Maybe it is not a space but a TAB?

Comment: I don't believe you.  If the last words are really separated by a space, then this works fine.  If they are really separated with a tab, then one does get this error.